# Does long-polling have performance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-pooling, comet, long-polling

I'm going to use long-polling in my asp.net mvc application. Some of the connections will probably be pending for response for more than 10 minutes. I know the connections will be "hung up" so they won't occupy the connections in IIS connection pool for a long time(correct me if I'm wrong). But with the amount of user grows, the concurrent connections will be more and more, the web server will have more "background" threads. Will it cause performance issue? If yes, what's the approximate order of magnitude that the server can handle? And what other *better solutions* should I take? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to use SignalR

Comment: @AD.Net: SignalR is pretty cool. However sometimes a web application has only one *real-time interactive interface* and people in the team(consider the tech manager) think it's an overkill to involve SignalR/Comet server in. So...

Comment: I would disagree, the server performance issue will be easier to handle with SignalR. You won't have to worry much about deployment, and it handles the connection pool for long polling if necessary.

Comment: @AD.Net: That's true. If there is a performance issue, I'll probably use SignalR. But before that I want to know if simple long-pooling does a good job for a proper magnitude (e.g. less than 1000 concurrent users).

Comment: Seems like you could put together a proof of concept test fairly easily. I can't recommend one, but there are load testing tools available http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Load_testing_tools

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet)